# Failed to push code on git?

Tags: git, github

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@173.255.206.222:apal.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pull the changes from the remote server before you can push your changes. So you should do `git pull --rebase` to rebase your changes on top of the remote ones. Then you can push.

Comment: To git@173.255.206.222:apal.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@173.255.206.222:apal.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.

Comment: You did the `git pull --rebase`? What did it output?

Comment: @ksimons is right. For a better understanding of git, here is a good read: http://gitolite.com/gcs/index.html